# cppcheck: function definitions in headers

Tags: c++, static-analysis, cppcheck

I'm trying to add a rule to a cppcheck for a function definitions (outside of class, or without inline) which are in *.h/*.hpp.

It looks like it's not doable without going into a cppcheck source code or without processing headers separately is that true?

Comment: Please, post some code. What has a `.h` file that makes it so different from any other `.cpp` file?

Comment: @Ripi2 I think it is quite clear what OP wants. Simply avoid function definitions in header file which are not declared inline. As long as a header is only used once the linker will not see any problem but maybe sometimes later the second include will crash the build. So it is a good idea to check for that before the header comes in use.

Comment: @Klaus CPPCHECK is quite old. It was designed in a simple way (e.g. by macros). I'm pointing out this simplicity. I don't think it can used as you would do with "normal" files for a big app.

Comment: @Ripi2: I only said that it is a good idea to check and for me it was clear what OP wants to check. That cppcheck is maybe the wrong tool might be right but was not part of my comment ;)

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realize that I could use include guard.

Answer (score 1):

sorry for late reply. It is true that you can't create a `rule` that is run by `--rule`. But you can create a `addon`.. python script that reads the xml output generated by `--dump`. See the manual for more information about addons.